# How to show two ListView on the same screen with Flutter?

Tags: listview, flutter, dart

I trying to make two `listView` in one screen, but the second listView only show half screen(lot of space at the bottom).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Flexible(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            child: _showFirstListView(),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: _showSecondListView(),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _showFirstListView() {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 1,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Text("First ListView");
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _showSecondListView() {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 15,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  height: 15,
                ),
                Text("FirstLine"),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 15,
                ),
                Text("SecondLine"),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 15,
                ),
                Text("ThirdLine"),
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

I have posted it on `dartpad`.
https://dartpad.dev/950d274dc06deb127d91d77b539c5db5

Comment: I am not sure what is the output you want?

Comment: Hey, just remove Fexible and use Expanded in your column of the build func for the first list. You have posted the right thing in dartpad. Look at your dartpad code.

Comment: The code you have shared on dartpad doesn't produce the space at the bottom?

Comment: @ShajedulIslamAny If I use `Expanded` for both, it will show both half screen. That not what I want. I want both listView in `wrap_content`.

Comment: @dlohani It did. It only show half height for the second listView.

Comment: For what you are trying to achieve, why do you even need two list views, why not just use  as single scroll view, and your two list as columns?

Comment: @Hoo How much items will be there in first `ListView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to remove the first `ListView` from a `Flexible` because you are already shrinking it to wrap and using both `shrinkWrap` and `Flexible` in the same list, will result on both lists sharing the same space 50/50, but you are actually shrinking the first one and the remaining space will be blank.

To avoid that, just let the list itself decide what space to use.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          child: _showFirstListView(),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: _showSecondListView(),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: If I use `Expanded` for both, it will show both half screen. That not what I want. I want both listView in `wrap_content`.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not getting what you are trying to achieve then. It might be a good idea if you could post a simple mock or so.

Comment: You can't open dartpad?

Comment: Yes, I can. and you have the first loose and the second using space left.

Comment: Did you see the second `ListView` only show half screen? It should show full, which mean the blue color should fill until "no issues" there.

Comment: @Hoo Here if the `_showFirstListView` contains so many list items, then you will get overflow error.

Comment: And also `_showSecondListView` will only use the remaining space even if it is 10 or even 0

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `Column`, use another `ListView` to contain both `_showFirstListView` and `_showSecondListView`.

Then your `ListView` in `_showFirstListView` and `_showSecondListView` should have

```
shrinkWrap: true,
physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
```

**Demo:** [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/bf8b083f9fa31bddbd4a439cda5bbef2)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          _firstListView(),
          _secondListView(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _firstListView() {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.green,
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 20,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(title: Text("FIRST $index")),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _secondListView() {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 20,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(title: Text("Second $index")),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's already answered, but for what you are trying to achieve, I don't know why do you even want to use two listviews that scroll separately, why not use a single list view. Try this, might be better than what you want.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
          Container(
             width: double.infinity,
            color: Colors.red,
            child: _showFirstListView(),
          ),
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: _showSecondListView(),
          ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _showFirstListView() {
    return Column(
    children: [
      ...[1].map((item) => Text("first listview")), //just in case you want to build from list of items as you would do in ListView.builder
    ],
    );
  }

  Widget _showSecondListView() {
    return Column(
    children: [
      //usually you already have a list of items you want to display
      ...[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15].map((item) => Container(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  height: 15,
                ),
                Text("FirstLine"),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 15,
                ),
                Text("SecondLine"),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 15,
                ),
                Text("ThirdLine"),
              ],
            ),
          )), //just in case you want to build from list of items as you would do in ListView.builder
    ],
    );
  }
}
```